# Unable to Obtain Failed Bulk API Records

Tags: bulk-api, postman, bulk-api-v2

I am trying to pull the failed records from a bulk job that I have using this API call:

```
https://COMPANYNAME.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v56.0/jobs/ingest/{jobId}/failedResults
```

This API call is not pulling anything in Postman, but I am able to pull data if I drop off the failedResults portion of the call.

I know that my results do have failed results from the returned JSON:

```
{
    "id": "{jobId}",
    "operation": "upsert",
    "object": "Object",
    "createdById": "{userId}",
    "createdDate": "2022-10-17T05:08:38.000+0000",
    "systemModstamp": "2022-10-17T05:09:04.000+0000",
    "state": "Closed",
    "externalIdFieldName": "{externalId}",
    "concurrencyMode": "Serial",
    "contentType": "ZIP_CSV",
    "apiVersion": 55.0,
    "jobType": "Classic",
    "numberRecordsProcessed": #######,
    "numberRecordsFailed": ##,
    "retries": 0,
    "totalProcessingTime": ########,
    "apiActiveProcessingTime": #######,
    "apexProcessingTime": ########
}
```

Should I be using something else than Postman to make this call or what could I do to pull these failed records?

Comment: I tried this in my Dev org using workbench and could see in the raw response that the below URI's are giving correct results`/services/data/v56.0/jobs/ingest/7507F00000XVC8qQAH/successfulResults/`   `/services/data/v56.0/jobs/ingest/7507F00000XVC8qQAH/failedResults/`
You might want to try workbench and let me know if you are stuck somewhere specifically

Answer (score 1):

I tried with below steps via workbench and could see the failedResults generated:

1. POST Method:
   `/services/data/v56.0/jobs/ingest`

Body:

```
{
"object": "Account",
"externalIdFieldName": "SLASerialNumber__c",
"contentType": "CSV",
"operation": "upsert",
"columnDelimiter": "COMMA",
"lineEnding": "CRLF"
}
```

Batch created with contentUrl: services/data/v56.0/jobs/ingest/7507F00000XVTynQAH/batches

---

2. PUT METHOD: `services/data/v56.0/jobs/ingest/7507F00000XVTynQAH/batches`

Header:

```
Content-Type: text/csv
Accept: application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

Body:

```
SLASerialNumber__c,Tradestyle,Name
1234,fashion,Maddali
1111,fashion
```

---

3. PATCH METHOD: `/services/data/v56.0/jobs/ingest/7507F00000XVTynQAH`

Header:

```
Accept: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
```

Body:

```
{"state":"UploadComplete"}
```

---

4. GET METHOD: `/services/data/v56.0/jobs/ingest/7507F00000XVTynQAH/failedResults/`

   "sf__Id","sf__Error",SLASerialNumber__c,Tradestyle,Name
   "","INVALID_FIELD:Number of fields in header is different from the row. header = 3 row = 2:--","","",""

[image: failed result]

`/services/data/v56.0/jobs/ingest/7507F00000XVTynQAH/successfulResults/`

```
"sf__Id","sf__Created",SLASerialNumber__c,Tradestyle,Name
"0017F00002RxEKDQA3","false","1234","fashion","Maddali"
```

[image]